# Cocos 2D - CCSprite makes crash with lldb

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

Hi I am kind of new to cocos 2D. I Use cocos2D v 2.x and created an app from cocos2D template. 
I Just added 5 CCSprite to my scene and after couple of minutes my fps gradually decreases below 10.0 and app crashes with lldb error. Here is my code for initial setup and other infos.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    window_ = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    CCGLView *glView = [CCGLView viewWithFrame:[window_ bounds]
                               pixelFormat:kEAGLColorFormatRGB565   //kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8
                               depthFormat:0    //GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24_OES
                        preserveBackbuffer:NO
                                sharegroup:nil
                             multiSampling:NO
                           numberOfSamples:0];
    [glView setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES];
    director_ = (CCDirectorIOS*) [CCDirector sharedDirector];
    director_.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
    [director_ setDisplayStats:YES];
    [director_ setAnimationInterval:1.0/60];
    [director_ setView:glView];
    [director_ setDelegate:self];
    [director_ setProjection:kCCDirectorProjection2D];

     if( ! [director_ enableRetinaDisplay:YES] )
        CCLOG(@"Retina Display Not supported");

    // Default texture format for PNG/BMP/TIFF/JPEG/GIF images
    // It can be RGBA8888, RGBA4444, RGB5_A1, RGB565
    // You can change anytime.
    [CCTexture2D setDefaultAlphaPixelFormat:kCCTexture2DPixelFormat_RGBA8888];

    // If the 1st suffix is not found and if fallback is enabled then fallback suffixes are going to searched. If none is found, it will try with the name without suffix.
    // On iPad HD  : "-ipadhd", "-ipad",  "-hd"
    // On iPad     : "-ipad", "-hd"
    // On iPhone HD: "-hd"
    CCFileUtils *sharedFileUtils = [CCFileUtils sharedFileUtils];
    [sharedFileUtils setEnableFallbackSuffixes:NO];             // Default: NO. No fallback suffixes are going to be used
    [sharedFileUtils setiPhoneRetinaDisplaySuffix:@"-hd"];      // Default on iPhone RetinaDisplay is "-hd"
    [sharedFileUtils setiPadSuffix:@"-ipad"];                   // Default on iPad is "ipad"
    [sharedFileUtils setiPadRetinaDisplaySuffix:@"-ipadhd"];    // Default on iPad RetinaDisplay is "-ipadhd"

    // Assume that PVR images have premultiplied alpha
    [CCTexture2D PVRImagesHavePremultipliedAlpha:YES];

    // and add the scene to the stack. The director will run it when it automatically when the view is displayed.
    [director_ pushScene: [IntroLayer scene]]; 


    // Create a Navigation Controller with the Director
    navController_ = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:director_];
    navController_.navigationBarHidden = YES;

    // set the Navigation Controller as the root view controller
        // [window_ addSubview:navController_.view];    // Generates flicker.
    [window_ setRootViewController:navController_];

    // make main window visible
    [window_ makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

and code in my HeloworldLayer.m in init method

```
- (id)init {

    if ((self=[super init])) {

        winSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;

        CCSprite * background =[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Bg.png" rect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768)];
        background.position=ccp(winSize.width/2, winSize.height/2); 
        [self addChild:background];

        CCSprite *bgstand=[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"back_side.png"];
        bgstand.position=ccp(winSize.width/2, winSize.height/2-150);
        [self addChild:bgstand];

        CCSprite *wheel=[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"wheel.png"];
        wheel.position=ccp(winSize.width/2, winSize.height/2+55);
        [self addChild:wheel];

        CCSprite *fgstand=[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"front_side.png"];
        fgstand.position=ccp(winSize.width/2, winSize.height/2-150);
        [self addChild:fgstand];

    }
    return self;
}
```

When i run my code i got these kind of log

```
2013-05-23 17:04:06.045 Box2Dtry[2333:c07] cocos2d: OS version: 6.1 (0x06010000)
2013-05-23 17:04:06.046 Box2Dtry[2333:c07] cocos2d: GL_VENDOR:   Apple Computer, Inc.
2013-05-23 17:04:06.046 Box2Dtry[2333:c07] cocos2d: GL_RENDERER: Apple Software Renderer
2013-05-23 17:04:06.047 Box2Dtry[2333:c07] cocos2d: GL_VERSION:  OpenGL ES 2.0 APPLE
2013-05-23 17:04:06.047 Box2Dtry[2333:c07] cocos2d: GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 4096
2013-05-23 17:04:06.048 Box2Dtry[2333:c07] cocos2d: GL_MAX_TEXTURE_UNITS: 8
2013-05-23 17:04:06.048 Box2Dtry[2333:c07] cocos2d: GL_MAX_SAMPLES: 4
2013-05-23 17:04:06.048 Box2Dtry[2333:c07] cocos2d: GL supports PVRTC: YES
2013-05-23 17:04:06.049 Box2Dtry[2333:c07] cocos2d: GL supports BGRA8888 textures: YES
2013-05-23 17:04:06.049 Box2Dtry[2333:c07] cocos2d: GL supports NPOT textures: YES
2013-05-23 17:04:06.049 Box2Dtry[2333:c07] cocos2d: GL supports discard_framebuffer: YES
2013-05-23 17:04:06.050 Box2Dtry[2333:c07] cocos2d: GL supports shareable VAO: NO
2013-05-23 17:04:06.050 Box2Dtry[2333:c07] cocos2d: compiled with Profiling Support: NO

2013-05-23 17:04:06.051 Box2Dtry[2333:c07] cocos2d: **** WARNING ****   CC_ENABLE_GL_STATE_CACHE is disabled. To improve performance, enable it by editing ccConfig.h

 2013-05-23 17:04:06.098 Box2Dtry[2333:c07] cocos2d: cocos2d v2.0.0
 2013-05-23 17:04:06.098 Box2Dtry[2333:c07] cocos2d: Using Director   Type:CCDirectorDisplayLink
2013-05-23 17:04:06.114 Box2Dtry[2333:c07] cocos2d: animation started with frame interval: 60.00
2013-05-23 17:04:06.115 Box2Dtry[2333:c07] cocos2d: surface size: 2048x1536
2013-05-23 17:04:07.432 Box2Dtry[2333:c07] cocos2d: CCTexture2D: Using RGB565 texture since image has no alpha
```

Comment: Where is this "lldb error"? Console log you posted doesn't have error logs.

Comment: comes only in debug mode...so you can ignore.

Comment: @Guru So if i proceed with this will it reflects in device too..?..

Comment: OPEN PROJECT IN XCODE, GOTO Product->Scheme->EditScheme set Build Configuration to Release, then run. No console log :)

Answer (score 0):

Because have launched the ipad retina on the simulator, you can see in debug:

```
2013-05-23 17:04:06.115 Box2Dtry[2333:c07] cocos2d: surface size: 2048x1536 //This is iPad retina
```

When you launch the ipad retina from the simulator with a old Mac , you see everything slowed.
Changes simulator type, or hardware type.